# SQL locks between databases

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql

Can a locked table on one database interfere with the operations of another database? The two databases aren't aware of each other. This is on SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these two databases are on the same server?

If so, then yes, activity in one database can have an effect on the server as a whole, impacting all databases.

All databases on a server share the same TempDB, they also share other system databases like MASTER and MSDB.

Its possible to have TempDB contention, and I've even seen situations where a schema change on a huge table in one database actually locked a table in the master database while the transaction was occuring, blocking other activity on the server.

Comment: Yes, both databases are on the same server. 

The problem is question is a complex SP that updates ~800k rows on a table, the process took about 8 hours and the dev team is claiming that it took that long because the WSUS database had some locks on it, which sincerely sounds like BS to me

Comment: Yeah, there is something else going on. I assume the "WSUS" database isn't explicitly referenced by the stored proc in question? My guess would be there is some other bad logic in the proc (like a cursor that walks through each row, then joins to the entire huge table each time, or something crazy like that)

Comment: Thanks. FYI, the WSUS is the Windows System Update Services DB, it has nothing to do with the problem DB